# How to validate an editableContent td in angular?

Tags: angular, validation, html-table, contenteditable

I want to validate my td in my angular application on my editable Table just like a form input something like with `[attr.required]`.

```
<tr *ngFor='let item of lists_arr; let i=index'>
  <td [attr.contenteditable]="displayingListIndeces[i]"
      [textContent]="lists_arr[i].list_serial_no"
      [attr.required]="true"
      (input)="lists_arr[i].list_serial_no=$event.target.textContent">
   {{item.list_serial_no}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

How can I achieve this. Is there any way good way to do it?

Comment: Why not use a `FormArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Reactive Forms approach for this. You can create a `FormGroup` with a `FormArray` in it. This `FormArray` will have the same number of `FormGroup` that you have in your `lists_arr`.

With that in place, you can apply `Validators.Required` while creating the `FormControl` for the `list_serial_no` attribute.

This will give you a flexibility to to apply validations on your `FormControl`s.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-table-eg) that implements something along the lines of it to give you some ref.

Comment: Can you please show some example . Will it  remove the tds or it can work with tds ? I wish to avoid the input fields

Comment: Why not? It will definitely work with `td`s. I've added a Sample StackBlitz for ref.

Comment: I will check it out.